# Cross compiling library linking (linux) (C++/C)

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi2, libusb

I have an issue when cross-compiling to my RPI2.
When compiling locally, everything is fine.

I am using Buildroot as cross-compiler,
every other program without lusb-1.0 works/compiles fine.

The library in this case is 'libusb-1.0'.

Compiling works fine:

```
g++ main.cpp -o run -lusb-1.0
```

Compilling issue:

```
arm-linux-g++ main.cpp -o run -lusb-1.0
```

error output:

```
main.cpp:2:31: fatal error: libusb-1.0/libusb.h: No such file or    
directory.
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
                              ^
```

program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout << "Test!" << endl;
 libusb_init(NULL);

 return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help, time and answers!

Comment: Same issues having with gcc compiler on C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had to re-select the library in Buildroot, and build the whole arm-compiler again.